# How to run CKeditor

Tags: javascript, node.js, ckeditor

I'm fairly new to javascript and just cloned the (static) CKeditor repo to fiddle with. I can't figure out how to run it! There is no obvious 'main' file and everything I run with node throws reference errors. Any help would be appreciated!

https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/tree/stable

Comment: Please do share some code or link to the repo, or maybe check their Read me section maybe they would've explain that in there.

Comment: Added a link. I have already read through the README.

Comment: I don't think CKeditor is a stand-alone app, so I think you need to implement that.

Comment: Check the "samples" directory inside the project root. The files in there show how to include the editor in a HTML page.

Comment: Negative marks on the question are completely unfair to the user who had a genuine question and came to the community for help. We punish him, instead of honestly stating that CKeditor documentation did a poor job (actually none in the area of configuration/setup) and like a lot of techie written docs, ASSUMES that you know what you're doing, IOW, you really don't need the documentation.
I ran into the same issue, until I saw a more appropriate and descriptive answer by @Reinmar. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

As others mentioned, CKEditor is not a standalone Node.JS's app, but an addon for your existing page. So first you need to create a web server which will run in Node.JS and then load CKEditor as a part of page generated by that web server.

Node.JS is just an JavaScript runtime, so it is not a web server itself (like e.g. PHP running on Apache). However, it's very easy to create web server with Node.JS. E.g. you can check the [Express framework](http://expressjs.com/) - see [getting started guide](http://expressjs.com/guide.html).

So you've got a web server. Now you can download CKEditor to the `public/` directory of your app generated by Express (see http://expressjs.com/guide.html#executable) and then you should follow the [CKEditor loading guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_ckeditor_js_load) to initialize it on page generated by Express.

The last step is to store data created in CKEditor. You'll find some basic examples of integrating Express with [Redis](http://redis.io/) database in the Express' guide, but in fact there are many databases and many web server frameworks for Node so you need to make some research first, which ones will satisfy your needs.

Answer (score 4):

CKEditor is a rich text editor library for the browser. It is not designed (and would have no use) in the Node.js environment.

Comment: How would I run it then? Sorry for the basicness of this question.

Comment: [Check out the documentation] for CKEditor. I suggest you start with a much, much smaller JavaScript repo if you're new to JavaScript and just looking for stuff to poke around with. CKEditor is pretty massive and a daunting starting point.