# Ckeditor using and integration in node.js web page

Tags: node.js, ckeditor, sails.js

how will we do integral ckeditor into Nodejs page? I added ckeditor integration codes to server.js file.But it isnt work.

Comment: The SO Grandmaster for CKEditor, Reinmar, Gives a brief intro here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16712600/694325

Answer (score 1):

This Q offers solutions [Node.js (sails.js) wysiwyg editor - images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378630/node-js-sails-js-wysiwyg-editor-images) at least with integrating with http://sailsjs.org/ per the Q.