# using ckeditor in sailsjs but filebrowser is not working

Tags: ckeditor, sails.js, ckfinder

I am using ckeditor latest version and full package in sailsjs. I am using file browse from server functionality.

```
//ckeditor/config.js

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '/files';
};
```

There is many images in assets/files folder. When i click on browse server then one new tab is opening and url is http://example.com/files?CKEditor=ck&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en

But i am getting default not found screen. But if i access image from url like http://example.com/files/ok.png. I Can see it in browser. But if i request http://example.com/files . I need to see list of images from files folder. What i need is the following or something file browser.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screen you provided shows [CKFinder](https://cksource.com/ckfinder) file manager, which can be easily integrated with CKEditor. CKFinder to work requires a server side connector - unfortunately, for now there's no connector for node.js.

You may find CKEditor [File Browser API](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_browser_api) helpful, as it allows to integrate any other file browser. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21581617/3719285) for a basic usage in sails.js.

Comment: I had already checked this. Bottom line is i have to write a file manager using sails.js and then have to follow http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_browser_api-section-example-1. BTW thanks for the answer.